# npm deasync cause crash in electron

Tags: node.js, crash, electron, electron-packager, node-deasync

Environment: Windows 10 Pro (x64) and electron 1.7.9 (also 1.8.3 )

Problem description:
The usage of "deasync" node module (version 0.1.11 and also 0.1.12) causes the crash of the renderer process.

In electron app, just using

`var deasync = require('deasync')`

as preload while creating BrowserWindow object, it cause the crash of the renderer.

The application crash randomically and also each time you come back from lock session:
1. run the application
2. lock session
3. unlock session
4. the renderer crash

I can also catch the crash event with

`mainWindow.webContents.on('crashed', (event) => {
    log.error( "crashed: ");
 });`

Any suggestions?

Comment: what does `deasync` do?

Comment: with deasync lib you can use async function as sync function https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync. In my context deasync lib works but cause the crashs as explained into the description.

Answer (score 1):

The deasync lib does not support Electron.

More details in the issue:
https://github.com/abbr/deasync/issues/95